# Accessing AWS AppSync without using API Keys in React Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

In my React Native App I am using API Keys with AWS AppSync and I want to move to using Cognito or IAM but with no user sign in.

My React Native app that just uses AWS Appsync to read to and write from DyanmoDB.

I initially set up the app to use API keys as it was easier to understand and I'm now attempting to transition to using AWS Cognito or IAM.

To do this in my AWS Console I changed the "Appsync->MyAppAPI->Settings->Default authorisation mode"/"API-level" from "API key" to "AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)".

I then created an Identity Pool and allowed "Enable access to unauthenticated identities".

My aws-exports file is

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile =  {
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://xxxxx.appsync-api.eu-west-x.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "eu-west-X",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AWS_IAM",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
};

export default awsmobile;
```

In my App.js file I have attempted to get the identityPoolId to be used and I have created this:

```
Amplify.configure({
    url: config.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
    region: config.aws_appsync_region,
    auth: {
      type: config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
      apiKey: config.aws_appsync_apiKey,
      region: 'eu-west-x',
      identityPoolId: 'eu-west-x:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    }
})
```

When I use the app to read from DynamoDB I get this error

> [WARN] 04:51.835 API - ensure credentials error, No Cognito Federated Identity pool provided

I then went back to the Cognito Manage Identity Pool page and changed my identity pool to use Cognito as an authentication source and provided a User Pool ID and an App client id. But I still get the same error.

I am fundamentally missunderstanding something, could you offer any insight?

Comment: Are you using Amplify to create graphql api?

Comment: I'm not certain. It was a few months ago that I built it and jumped to another one, before coming back to this one. I think I did use Amplify but I'm not certain.

Comment: no answers huh... I'm about to go through this process myself. Did you ever figure it out?